# Kotlin files not recognized in Flutter app

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

I am working on a Flutter app inside of the latest stable version of Android Studio. I need to use a native SDK in this project since that vendor does not yet support Flutter. The example I am working off of was using the old support libraries and that was causing trouble so I am migrating things to androidx. I notice though that as I attempt to fix the errors in an Activity, like Unresolved reference: AppCompatActivity for example, that Android Studio **does not recognize the Activity as a Kotlin file**. In other words, none of the hints that show up work and in fact, no typo is ever shown as a syntax error. It's treating the Activity like a plain text file! You can type anything you want (like this_is_clearly_a_syntax_error as a line by itself) and no highlighting of an error will occur.

How do you get the Kotlin files to be treated like they do in a normal Android app?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you have to go in an physically mark the android directory as Source. So, go to File->Project Structure then select Module on the left. Left click on Android, then select Source then hit Apply.

Comment: you are very right! I beforehand as well added an SDK e.g. CTRL+shift+alt+s project then select android api 30 platform (the example project didnt have the project SDK set somehow, and nothing was complaining)

Comment: actually might be wrong, real correct answer might be this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64359540/533426