# Unresolved reference: FlutterActivity

Tags: flutter

I was researching a bit about writing native code in flutter. On opening the MainActivity.kt file in android I faced these issues.

[image]

On highlighting the error it showed 'Unresolved reference: FlutterActivity'.

Can someone please help me to fix this issue ?

Thankyou in advance.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I got the solution for this.

If you want to write native code or edit existing native code you have to open the "android" part of your project specifically.

You can do that be going to : File -> Open .....

Then browse to your current project and select its "android" folder and open it :

[image]

Then click "OK".

It will open the android native part of your project. All the errors will be gone if you will open the MainActivity through this path.

Comment: Still it's a bug in the IDE. Someone should open a ticket for it. I will if I get around to it.

Comment: The error still remains in the IDE - does anyone know how to clear this? (I dont want to work in the MainActivity)

Comment: The error disappears when, as stated above, you open the android module as a NEW Android Studio project, not from within the same IDE page you use for the Flutter project

Comment: They should also emphasise this point [here in the Flutter docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-channels).

Comment: This doesn't fix the issue in the main project, you need to open the second "Android" project. So, if you just want to get rid of the warning (as I did), it won't help at all.

Answer (score 1):

just open it in android project view in a new window then finish it until it build. then if you get any error debug it there. but if it is built successfully and shows an error in flutter project view leave it it is just the editor bug.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGkrc.png

Answer (score 1):

In my case it helped to import the `android` folder of the Flutter project as a Gradle project. Once Gradle finished building and indexing, the error went away.